# mat-selection-list with async options resets reactive control value on options change

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I have a simple select with options coming from observable:

```html
    <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false" [formControl]="itemSelect">
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)?.edges " [value]="item.node.id">
        {{item.node.name}}
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

It renders fine the first time, but when `items$` fires an update, the view is updated correctly, but `itemSelect` gets its value reset to empty array.

However if I replace `mat-selection-list` with `mat-select`, it keeps the value.

And with a plain html select, it resets both value and view.

So what should I do to keep the value for all cases?

Comment: Does mat-list-option have a selected attribute?

Comment: @JohnPeters Yes they do. And it is possible to hide reactive control behind the select (selectionChange) event and options [selected] binding, but I'm wondering why it doesn't work naturally.

Comment: The current formContol is only for the select control. It should have a selected items property than can be bound. But what I do is bind the option selected property to a field or property in the option model. [(selected)]='model.property===somevalue'  Also remember that formcontrol bindings force us to set and get values from them instead of directly accessing the elements. There is a way to bypass that to see changed values and sometimes needs to be used, but rarely